# Laravel Update route on form submit

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm using resourceful controller,

**Routes.php**

```
Route::resource('admin/reports', 'ReportController');
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open([ 'route' => array('admin/reports', $report->id),'class' => 'form', 'method' => 'PUT', 'id' => 'reporteditform', 'name' => 'reporteditform', 'files' => true ]) !!}
{!! csrf_field() !!}
 .............
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

When I submit the form, It gives me following error

```
 ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 306: Route [admin/reports] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\sampleproject\resources\views\admin\reports\edit.blade.php)
```

Am I doing something wrong with form action url ? 
Any help is much appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`route()` method needs name of the route as an argument.

```
'route' => array('reports', $report->id)
```

Add name to your route as below:

```
Route::resource('admin/reports', 'ReportController')->name('reports');
```

Reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-route

You can also use `url()`. replace `route` in following to `url`:

```
'route' => array('reports', $report->id)

'url' => array('admin/reports', $report->id)
```

Comment: If I change the route in this way that you answered, I have to change routes to all places in my project..earlier with some other form in the same project , I used one route for update this way "'route' => array('inspector.update', $user->id)" and its working. Can you just modify answer with resourceful route "admin/reports" ?

Comment: so you can replace the `route()` with `url()` . problem solved